# css - Is there any way to disable css elements with another css element

Tags: css

I have a `hidden-print` class that is working just fine. I'm wondering, how can i use that to hide a certain id of css also? for example here.

```
<style>
        #page-content
     {
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.428571429;
        color: #4d4d4d;
        background-color: #f7f8fa;
        margin-left:230px
    }
</style>

<div id="page-content">

...
...
</div>
```

how can i use that `hidden-print` to just specifically remove that `margin-left:230px`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added style demonstration as per your update.  Anything between the curly braces under @media print will adjust the printed page look and layout, without affecting screen appearance.

```
    <style>
                    #page-content
             {
                    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
                    font-size: 14px;
                    line-height: 1.428571429;
                    color: #4d4d4d;
                    background-color: #f7f8fa;
                    margin-left:230px
            }

    @media print 
    {
            /*  adjust margin  */
            #page-content 
            {
            margin-left: 0px 
            }

            /*  for items you don't want on printed page . . . */
            #page-footer 
            {
            display: none;
            }

            /* any class item which should be altered for printing, such as dark backgrounds which don't always print well. */
            .some-element-class 
            {
            background: White;
            color: Black;
            }
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: is the `print` in @media print is a .css file?

Comment: Oh, yes.  That would go in your css file same as other queries like screen width queries.  You can also use :  "display: none" for elements you don't want to print at all.

Comment: Sorry I can't comprehend the documentation. I've update my question